# how to update the every sec in jquery

Tags: php, jquery

I am trying to get the data from the php file and update every second so when the information changes in the php file it will auto update

```
 $(document).ready(function() { 
$.ajaxSetup ({
    cache: false
});
 $("#hidden").hide(); 
 $("#textfield").val(""); 
 $("#textarea").val(""); 

 var hol=$(this).attr('myval'); 
 var formContent ="action=getlink&link="+hol; 

 $.getJSON("inc/json.php",formContent, function(json){ 
 $("#textfield").val(json.name); 
 $("#textarea").val(json.desc); 
 $("#formHeader").text("Edit"); 
 $("#ajaxBox").text("All info loaded OK"); 
 });


 });
```

Comment: Great! What is the question, though?

Comment: You should probably restate the question in the description. I think you mean "How to update this every second in jquery?"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use setInterval(), not setTimeout().  setInterval will call the function at your specified interval.

```
var interval = setInterval(function() { 
    /* do something that will execute every 1000 milliseconds*/ 
}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 3):

Put that code in a function and call setTimeout()

Answer (score 0):

This will call when it receives a response or an error and retry.  Possibly a more elegant solution than checking every second.

```
function foo()
{   
 $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: ,
        data: ,
        timeout:50000, /* Timeout in ms */

        success: function(data){ /* called when request completes */
                'foo()', /* Request next message */
            );
        },
        error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown){
            setTimeout(
                'foo()', /* Try again after.. */
                "15000"); /* milliseconds (1second) */
        },
    });
}
```